# Knockout.js is turning numbers into strings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to do a simple Timesheet demo and I'm having some issues with my computed observables which insist on converting my numbers to strings and concatenating them instead of adding them. JavaScript is not my specialty.

The code is:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    self = this;
    this.RegSun = ko.observable(0);
    this.RegMon = ko.observable(0);
    this.RegTue = ko.observable(0);
    this.RegWed = ko.observable(0);
    this.RegThu = ko.observable(0);
    this.RegFri = ko.observable(0);
    this.RegSat = ko.observable(0);
    this.HolSun = ko.observable(0);
    this.HolMon = ko.observable(0);
    this.HolTue = ko.observable(0);
    this.HolWed = ko.observable(0);
    this.HolThu = ko.observable(0);
    this.HolFri = ko.observable(0);
    this.HolSat = ko.observable(0);

    this.RegSun.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });
    this.RegMon.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });
    this.RegTue.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });
    this.RegWed.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });
    this.RegThu.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });
    this.RegFri.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });
    this.RegSat.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });
    this.HolSun.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });
    this.HolMon.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });
    this.HolTue.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });
    this.HolWed.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });
    this.HolThu.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });
    this.HolFri.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });
    this.HolSat.extend({ required: true, min: 0, max: 24 });

    this.RegTot = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.RegSun() + self.RegMon() + self.RegTue() + self.RegWed() + self.RegThu() + self.RegFri() + self.RegSat();
    });
    this.HolTot = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.HolSun() + self.HolMon() + self.HolTue() + self.HolWed() + self.HolThu() + self.HolFri() + self.HolSat();
    });
    this.TotSun = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.RegSun() + self.HolSun();
    });
    this.TotMon = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.RegMon() + self.HolMon();
    });
    this.TotTue = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.RegTue() + self.HolTue();
    });
    this.TotWed = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.RegWed() + self.HolWed();
    });
    this.TotThu = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.RegThu() + self.HolThu();
    });
    this.TotFri = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.RegFri() + self.HolFri();
    });
    this.TotSat = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.RegSat() + self.HolSat();
    });
    this.TotTot = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.RegTot() + self.HolTot();
    });
};
```

and the HTML is:

```
<table class="workspacetable">
    <thead><tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th><th>Total</th></tr></thead>
    <tr><td>Regular</td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: RegSun" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: RegMon" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: RegTue" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: RegWed" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: RegThu" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: RegFri" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: RegSat" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><span data-bind="text: Number(RegTot())">&nbsp;</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Holiday</td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: HolSun" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: HolMon" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: HolTue" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: HolWed" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: HolThu" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: HolFri" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><input type="text" data-bind="value: HolSat" class="timesheethours" /></td><td><span data-bind="text: HolTot">&nbsp;</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Total</b></td><td><span data-bind="text: TotSun">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span data-bind="text: TotMon">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span data-bind="text: TotTue">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span data-bind="text: TotWed">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span data-bind="text: TotThu">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span data-bind="text: TotFri">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span data-bind="text: TotSat">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span data-bind="text: TotTot">&nbsp;</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pdavis68/umk0bh4L/2/)

If you enter a value for one of the dates in the fiddle, the problem should immediately be apparent. Surely I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Holy code repetition Pete. Have you considered using an array?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Did I mention it's a demo? I probably wouldn't implement it this way in the real system. But actually, with VS.NET's column editing, it's a piece of cake to do it this way.

Comment: Even for a "demo", I'm with @BenjaminGruenbaum on this one. That amount of repetition just hurts my eyes. You'd learn a lot more if you tried to do it properly.

Comment: I have over 30 years of development experience (not with JavaScript, of course). I understand your issues, but I have reasons specific to this demo that I did it this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are strings because they are bound to textboxes which take strings. You need to convert them back to numbers. Something like:

```
this.TotSun = ko.computed(function() {
    return parseInt(self.RegSun(),10) + parseInt(self.HolSun(),10);
});
```

See [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Note: look at `parseFloat` if you need to support floating point values.

But as @BenjaminGruenbaum said in the comments, you really need to learn to use arrays.